# use a 'dynamic' static property across multiple users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, static, session-variables

I'm trying to understand if there is any issue with doing a 'dynamic' static property. Say, I have an `ASP.NET Webforms` application that deals with Employees in a company. For the sake of this question, lets say this application is built for only one company.

Assume there is a class called Employee. It contains one static property.

```
public static string CompanyName = "My Company";
```

Now anywhere on the site if I use CompanyName, it is going to display the same company name for all users. A true static usage.

Now assume I define another property as (Lets say this is for ease of usage across the site so you can just do `Employee.LoggedIn`. )

```
public static Employee LoggedIn
{
   get 
   {
     return Session["LoggedInEmployee"] As Employee;
   }
}
```

This will return different values for different employees based on what user is connected to the site. Does this mean there is a copy of this variable for every user? I know this works as expected but just wondering if it is safe to do this.

*EDIT* - i'm not looking for better ways to do this. I'm only trying to understand how the static property can hold different values. Someone commented saying the 'get' is a method, but still the property is represented as static.

Comment: Sure that seems like a reasonable thing to do.  Is LoggedIn going to be in the application class or something?

Comment: Property getter is a method, it does not have any state by itself... So it is not clear what your mean "copy of this variable" - there is no "variables" in your sample (`Session` is *property* of `Page` class)...

Comment: When using session in its default mode of InProc, all session data will be stored in memory on the server (until is expires). So if you have a high number of users and Employee object has a lot of data, then you could run into memory pressure on your web server. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx for more info

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string CompanyName = "My Company";
```

We don't normally use Singleton in ASP.Net except for IoC container, Logging or Caching.

```
public Employee static LoggedIn
{
   return Session["LoggedInEmployee"] As Employee;
}
```

Above code won't even compile.

> This will return different values for different employees based on
>   what user is connected to the site. Does this mean there is a copy of
>   this variable for every user? I know this works as expected but just
>   wondering if it is safe to do this.

Based on your question, you want LoggedInEmployee available across your application.

If I understand your question correctly, **LoggedInEmployee** is the current logged-in employee's information. If so, it shouldn't be shared with other logged-in employee.

Since it is per logged-in employee information, I'll use the alternative approach by storing in [HttpContext](http://odetocode.com/articles/111.aspx) which is only available to current logged-in employee.

```
public class MyContext
{
    private MyUser _myUser;

    public static MyContext Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items["MyContext"] == null)
            {
                MyContext context = new MyContext();
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("MyContext", context);
                return context;
            }
            return (MyContext) HttpContext.Current.Items["MyContext"];
        }
        }

        public MyUser MyUser
        {

            get { return _myUser; }
            set { _myUser = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

### Global.asax

```
void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && 
        HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        MyContext.Current.MyUser = 
           YOURCODE.GetUserByUsername(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
var user = MyContext.Current.MyUser;
```

## ## Back to Original Question ##

```
public static class EmployeeHelper {
   public static Employee LoggedIn {
      get { return HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedInEmployee"] as Employee; }
   }
}
```

Above approach is fine. As long as you do not make like this -

```
public static class EmployeeHelper {
   // ===== Bad approach =====
   private static HttpSessionState _session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
   public static Employee LoggedIn {
      get { return _session["LoggedInEmployee"] as Employee; }
   }
}
```

Comment: i'm really just trying to understand how a static property holds different values - someone commented saying its really a method (get) - but LoggedIn is still a static property of the employee class.

Comment: ok, so I guess the private and public static properties/fields behave differently.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually how ASP.NET MVC handles some of its code as well. For example, when you do `HttpContext.Current` it does something very similar to your `LoggedIn` call. It's a static property that depends on the current request lifecycle under which it was called. I wouldn't worry much about it as `static` enforces one reference, but that reference's value can be context-specific, sort of like `ThreadStaticAttribute`

Comment: that's what i'm trying to understand - how exactly is one reference holding multiple values. what if two users simultaneously access it?

Comment: There are objects built-in to the .NET framework to allow this sort of behaviour. One in particular is [ThreadLocal<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Also, each user comes in on their own thread, and that's why this works. Each thread keeps its own local storage via `ThreadLocal<T>` type classes.